# Configuring IIS6 web application to use other port number

Tags: iis-6

I have a web application configured in IIS6 under "Default Web Site". By default the application is using port 80 for communication. I need to change it some other port number, without affecting other applications.

Is that possible? If it is then please provide proper steps for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you will end up with a new site.

In IIS > Right click "Web Sites" > New > Web Site. Specify a name for the site and the IP address / port combination.

You'll want to specify your new port and ensure the port doesn't conflict with the list of ports used with the existing site.

Answer (score 2):

In IIS > Right click the Default Web Site, and change the TCP port on the Web Site tab.

What other applications are you talking about being affected?

EDIT: To avoid messing with other virtual directories that need to stay on 80, you would want to create a new site on the port you want, and leave the old site on 80.

Comment: thanks! by other applications means virtual directories.